# Good way to create class object instance according to a string value in c++?

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

See the code snip for the question:

```
class Base; 
typedef Base* BasePtr; 

template<typename D>
BasePtr CreateDerivedClass() {
    return new D();
}

class D1 : public Base {
....
};

class D2 : public Base {
....
}

void main() {
    std::string derived_name = {"D1", "D2"}; 
    std::vector<BasePtr> derived_vec; 
    for (auto& name : derived_name) {
// QUESTION: Other than factory design pattern, how can I pass the derived 
// class typename which is the value of string "name" to CreateDerivedClass<name> ?
        derived_vec.push_back(CreateDerivedClass<name>()); 
    }
}
```

Note: Here, I don't want to use the factory design pattern which required the derived class register itself during definition.

Comment: There are many methods to create a variable from a string value.  See `strtoul`, `std::istringstream`.  Since you didn't specify the *type* of variable, see also `std::string::substr`.

Comment: Although you don't have to register during definition, you still have to register at some point.

Comment: I agree with @Remy, a map holding the factory functions keyed by the stringized class names seems to be the best way. This map can be maintained in one place. Though self registration of the classes sounds even better, because you just have to consider that when implementing another derived class. I always have to manage it in a single file.

Comment: ^^^^ Note: Doesn't work with templates.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Thank you @drescherjm, what I am trying to figure out is if I can do this without registering the class. Now I got it that it is not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Template parameter values must be known at compile-time.  There is simple no way to *directly* convert a string *at runtime* to a type for use in a template parameter.  You will have to compare the string value at runtime to decide which `CreateDerivedClass` specialization to call.

For instance, the simplest way to handle this is to use a `std::map` where its elements hold pointers to the specialized functions that you want to be able to call, eg:

```cpp
using createFuncType = BasePtr (*)();
std::map<std::string, createFuncType> createFuncs;
createFuncs["D1"] = &CreateDerivedClass<D1>;
createFuncs["D2"] = &CreateDerivedClass<D2>;
...
```

Then you can do this:

```cpp
std::string derived_names[] = {"D1", "D2"}; 
std::vector<BasePtr> derived_vec; 
for (auto& name : derived_names) {
    derived_vec.push_back(createFuncs[name]());
}
```

There is really no other option in this situation.

---

That being said, you should be using `std::unique_ptr<Base>` instead of raw `Base*` pointers, eg:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
using createFuncType = BasePtr (*)();

template<typename D>
BasePtr CreateDerivedClass() {
    return std::make_unique<D>();
}

class D1 : public Base {
    ...
};

class D2 : public Base {
    ...
}

...

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, createFuncType> createFuncs;
    createFuncs["D1"] = &CreateDerivedClass<D1>;
    createFuncs["D2"] = &CreateDerivedClass<D2>;
    ...

    std::string derived_names = {"D1", "D2", ...};
    std::vector<BasePtr> derived_vec; 
    for (auto& name : derived_names) {
        derived_vec.push_back(createFuncs[name]()); 
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Yes, I used the factory design pattern and applied a map holding the factory function. What I am trying to figure out is if it is possible to do that without registering the class. Now it is clear that it is not possible, I have to register the class somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The type T of the template should be known in compilation time, this is because the compiler needs to create the piece of code matching to the implementation of the class/function with the type T. This is how templates in C++ work.
What if `derived_names` will consist the value `"D8"` which is not a known type, we are going to have a trouble.